# Error running "hdfs.put()" in RHadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, rhadoop

I am using RHadoop for my project on sentiment analysis. When I try to run `hdfs.put()` I am recieving the following error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=user, access=WRITE, inode="/":hduser:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesy
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a permission denied error. You are running the command as `user`. Just run `su hduser` before your command (the error states that `hduser` has the required permissions). Or grant `user` the required permissions with `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

`user` don't have permission to access the `/`. Try by changing the path to user home